# How to Pass variables to python script?

Tags: python

I know it can be achieved by command line but I need to pass at least 10 variables and command line will mean too much of programming since these variables may or may not be passed.

Actually I have build A application half in vB( for GUI ) and Half in python( for script ). I need to pass variables to python, similar, to its keywords arguments, i.e, x = val1, y = val2. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you doing that passing ten command line arguments is so much more work than passing one?

Comment: @relet Couldn't get you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Python <2.7 I would suggest [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html).
optparse is deprecated though, and in 2.7 you should use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

It makes passing named parameters a breeze.

Comment: +1 for mentioning optparse, which is more powerful than getopt.

Answer (score 6):

you can do something fun like call it as

```
thepyscript.py "x = 12,y = 'hello world', z = 'jam'"
```

and inside your script,

parse do:

```
stuff = arg[1].split(',')
for item in stuff:
    exec(item) #or eval(item) depending on how complex you get 
#Exec can be a lot of fun :) In fact with this approach you could potentially  
#send functions to your script.
#If this is more than you need, then i'd stick w/ arg/optparse
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working on windows with VB, it's worth mentioning that [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) might be one option.  Since both VB and IronPython can interact through .NET, you could wrap up your script in an assembly and expose a function which you call with the required arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [getopt module](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html)? It's designed to make working with command line options easier. See also the examples at  [Dive Into Python](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html).

If you are working with Python 2.7 (and not lower), than you can also have a look at the [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) which should make it even easier.

Comment: Actually, `argparse` *is* available for Python < 2.7!  It is just that it is an optional module (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse)…

Answer (score 1):

If your script is not called too often, you can use a configuration file.

[The .ini style is easily readable by ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html):

```
[Section_1]
foo1=1
foo2=2
foo3=5
...

[Section_2]
bar1=1
bar2=2
bar3=3
...
```

If you have a serious amount of variables, it might be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about creating a python script setting these variables from the gui side? When starting the python app you just start this script and you have your vars.

[Execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile)