# Pass variable from a server web to python?

Tags: python, html

I´m running a html page on a server (using Xampp). Now, I would like take a variable from this html and pass it to python but i don´t the way. I don´t know if I can use Flask because I am running the html with Xampp.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass variables to python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434048/how-to-pass-variables-to-python-script)

Comment: In this case i need to pass it from a html

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50281153) question you posted two hours earlier? Please don't duplicate questions.